# Enable Magento Varien_Profiler in admin area

Tags: magento, profiling

How do I enable Magento Profiler in the admin area?

I've set the admin option, added `Varien_Profiler::enable();` before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` and cleared cache, but the profiler results only show in frontend?

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check that profiler is enabled as well *in the default configuration scope* in **System > Configuration > Developer** and that Developer IP Restrictions are empty or configured correctly.

**Edit:** Based on this being the accepted answer, it's worth nothing that the "default scope" in the system configuration will store values against the store scope ID of 0, which is the store scope which the admin areas uses.