# how to enable profiler for magento backend

Tags: php, magento

I want to use magento profiler for admin area. Is there any option in magento admin to do that or there is any other mysql query to do that?

i am using magento 1.8

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186700/enable-magento-varien-profiler-in-admin-area

Comment: thanks for reply i asking for profiler for magento admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that solution i run following mysql queries to do that:

`select * from core_config_data where path like '%template_hints%' and scope like '%default%';`

this query will output 2 rows set there value attribute from 0 to 1, if you get no records by the upper query run that follow query

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0,'dev/debug/template_hints', 1),('default', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
```

to disable it change the value to 0 again

Answer (score 0):

Magento Profiler and Template Hints are two different things.

To enable Profiler you need to uncomment `Varien_Profiler::enable();` line found in `index.php` and set configuration in `System > Configuration > Developer > Debug` minding the current configuration scope.

To enable Template Path Hints in admin use this:

```
insert into core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) 
values ('stores', 0, 'dev/debug/template_hints', 1)
on duplicate key update value = 1 &~ value;
```